# Calculate coordinates from normal vector and center

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Lets say I have `2D plane`, `normal vector`, and `X,Y coordinates of center of the line`.
How can I **calculat**e **start point** of the line and **end point** of the line? (lets say length of line is 100mm but it doesnt matter).

Edit: I have center of the line and normal vector and I need to calculate both ends of the line like their positions X,Y.
[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mtrn.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the normal vector is $\large n = (n_x, n_y)$ , then from this you can compute the direction vector of the line segment as $\large d = (n_y, -n_x) $.  Normalize vector $d$ by dividing by its length to obtain vector $\hat{d}$ as follows

$\large \hat{d} = \dfrac{ (n_y, -n_x) }{\sqrt{ n_x^2 + n_y^2} } $

Now if the midpoint of the line segment is $M = (m_x, m_y)$ and its length is $L$, then the endpoints are

$\large A = M + \left(\dfrac{L}{2}\right) \hat{d}$

and

$\large B = M - \left(\dfrac{L}{2}\right) \hat{d}$